# Can I use OpenGL in my Java applications? If yes, how?

Tags: java, opengl, 3d

I want to start creating some 3D software for Linux, and heard that OpenGL is the library of choice for Linux 3D development.

Is there any way to use it with Java? if yes, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are lots of ways to use OpenGL in Java. For example:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_OpenGL
[LWJGL](http://lwjgl.org/)

**EDIT**

Additionally, since you're new to programming. You may want to get a handle on some of the basics of programming before taking on 3D graphics. I've got a friend who is new to programming started on [these tutorials](http://eclipsetutorial.sourceforge.net/totalbeginner.html). No verdict on how good they are yet, but should make a good start.

Comment: Personally I'm using LWJGL. I'd say it's nice to use, and would recommend it. However I haven't used other options much more than setting up basic scenes when I was researching which one to go with.

Comment: thanks, good answer and great tutorials

Comment: And after you are done with that check out http://nehe.gamedev.net/ for OpenGL tutorials. Mostly in C, but there are Java attached examples as well.

Answer (score 3):

I like [LWJGL](http://lwjgl.org/), it's got several ways to make life just that little bit easier for game developers. Just bear in mind that 3D graphics is pretty daunting. Don't be discouraged if you don't get the camera pointing the right way on your first try.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and you probably need to setup [JOGL in eclipse](http://timelessname.com/jogl/lesson01/).

Answer (score 1):

The kits mentioned so far, LWJGL, JOGL are good suggestions.

If you are just looking to play around and make neat things I suggest looking at [JMonkeyEngine](http://jmonkeyengine.com/). It won't get you as close to the metal as the other libraries but you can jump into making something neat a lot quicker then the raw API's.

Comment: thank you, I will definately check it out

Answer (score 1):

Answer is simple, you can use JOGL.